# Sencha Touch List of a panel

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a app set up and on my hoe page/screen several links.  When I click on a link it will then display a list of items (like a contact list ), then again a detailed view when the list item is clicked on as well.

I have the following set up:

```
  App.views.Viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
   fullscreen: true,
   layout: 'card',
   cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
   dockedItems: [
       {
        dock : 'top',
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        title: '<img src="res/img/generic/TT_Small.png" />',
        cls: 'homeHeader'
       },
    ],

 });
```

and the view I want as a list is:

```
  App.views.HomeAbout = Ext.regModel('Contact', {
  fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
  });

  var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
  model : 'Contact',
  root: 'images',
  sorters: 'firstName',

  getGroupString : function(record) {
  return record.get('firstName')[0];
  },


  data: [
  {firstName: 'Tommy', lastName: 'Maintz'},
  {firstName: 'Rob', lastName: 'Dougan'},
  {firstName: 'Ed', lastName: 'Spencer'},
  {firstName: 'Jamie', lastName: 'Avins'},
  {firstName: 'Aaron', lastName: 'Conran'},
  {firstName: 'Dave', lastName: 'Kaneda'},
  {firstName: 'Michael', lastName: 'Mullany'},
  {firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'},
  {firstName: 'Jay', lastName: 'Robinson'}
  ]
  });
```

var list = new Ext.List({
      fullscreen: true,
      itemTpl : '{firstName} {lastName}',
            grouped : true,
      indexBar: false,

```
  store: store
  });
```

I am using the simple 'contact' eg to start with so once running I will amend my data etc as needed, but when I click on the link to go to this view I get the following

```
  Uncaught Attempting to create a component with an xtype that has not been registered: HomeAbout
```

But in my controller i have :

```
  about: function()
{
    if ( ! this.aboutView)
    {
        this.aboutView = this.render({
            xtype: 'HomeAbout',
        });
    }.....
```

Any ideas or help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change:

```
App.views.HomeAbout = Ext.regModel('Contact', {
  fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
 });
```

to

```
App.models.Contact = Ext.regModel('Contact', {
  fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']  
});
```

Then have this

```
App.views.HomeAbout = Ext.extend(Ext.List, { 
    fullscreen: true,
    itemTpl : '{firstName} {lastName}',
    grouped : true,
    indexBar: false, 
    store: store
});
```

instead of `var list...`

and finally reg the new xtype - class that extends default sencha-touch class - like this

```
Ext.reg('HomeAbout', App.views.HomeAbout);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I see you edited it as it was different twice :-).  I have left my list in so that I then items : [list], to the panel this way it keeps the toolbar at the top so I can the us the back etc thanks

Comment: How would i add a click event this these in order to then goto a static detail veiw for each?

Comment: add this:
`onItemDisclosure:function(record){}` to the configuration of the App.views.HomeAbout. The `record`is the object that was clicked.

Comment: I found this and did this just need the code inside to view the clicked page, thanks